# How to get the user of the parent process?

Tags: bash, config, sudo, pid

I'm writing a program which uses its own config files (in /etc/program/ and ~/.config/program/)
The problem is sometimes it needs to be executed as root (so most of the time with sudo) and in this case ~/.config/program is actually in root's directory (/root in my case)
I want my program to use the user's config file even if used with sudo. My idea is to first get the parent program's PID (in my case BASH) -- which is normally executed by a normal user -- and then get the name of the user executing the parent program. I easly found out how to get the PPID, but I didn't found how to find the name of the user.

I imagine a script like :

`parents_name=$(echo $PPID | *command_which_gives_the_name_from_a_PID*)`

`. /home/$parents_name/.config/program      # includes the user's config file`

I hope someone have an awnser !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` adds the name of the invoking user to the environment of the command.

```
. /home/$SUDO_USER/.config/program
```

`$HOME` *might* already be the same as `/home/$SUDO_USER`, but there are too many ways to configure `sudo` to make it the home directory of the target user.

However, that makes your script dependent on being *called* by `sudo`. Better to be explicit and pass the path of the desired configuration to the script as an argument. Something like

```
sudo theScript "$HOME/.config/program"
```

and

```
. "$1"
```

Comment: Thanks ! works perfectly ! I added an if instruction :
if test "$SUDO_USER"
then
      path="/home/$SUDO_USER/.config/program"
else
      path="/home/$USER/.config/program"

Comment: Is this for every -nix OS?

Comment: Presumably; `sudo` is not part of any OS, but a separate (though commonly installed) utility.

Comment: @chepner, sorry I meant whether SUDO uses /.config/program, but now I realize that was the OP's config sript he meant to run. disregard. and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get the user of a process

```
$ ps u -p 2813
```

To strip it out

```
$ ps u -p 2813 | awk '{print $1}'
USER
john
```

Or

```
$ ps -o user= -p 2813
john
```

Answer (score 0):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284934/return-owner-of-process-given-pid/284938 has a similar question.  The accepted answer was to use `ps -o user= -p PIDHERE`.  So, in your case, you'd do something like:

```sh
parents_name=$(ps -o user= -p $PPID)
```

In this case, we don't want column headers, so we add `--no-headers`.

Comment: Brian, I think "user --no-headers" is the same as "user=", but not sure if this applies to all -nix OS. Ok for mac OS.

Comment: @P2000 I just tried it and it worked on linux too.  I'm updating the answer accordingly.